# Woocommerce not displaying local tax rate

Tags: woocommerce

My WooCommere installation is not adding local taxes after the user is entering the US Zipcode. The backend seems to have all the zipcodes and tax rates. How do I fix the problem?

Answer (score 1):

I was having this same issue. It may not be the same for you, but I finally figured out that the country code was wrong. I was using USA instead of US... and it requires the 2 letter code instead. And I couldn't just change it, I actually had to create a new tax instance with the same info, but with the US code instead.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Other possible issue is that in the settings you dont have "calculate taxes based on CUSTOMER address"

Answer (score 1):

You can download the raw data from http://www.taxrates.com/state-rates

Then adapt it to WooCommerce format, following their example here:

[your wordpress folder / site]/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/dummy-data/sample_tax_rates.csv

Make sure to multiply the tax rate by 100 (woo commerce expects tax in %) - you can use excel etc, just make sure to leave saved as .csv.

Having said that, the tax isn't always calculated in Woo (e.g. if the city is different - "New York, New York" doesn't have an entry, but "New York City, New York" does.  I recommend you remove the city names altogether and just rely on zip codes (as inaccurate as they can potentially be).

Remember also that you're only required to collect Sales tax where you have a "Nexus" too https://www.sba.gov/content/collecting-sales-tax-over-internet

Answer (score 0):

WooCommerce would not able to handle tax table that has a lot of entries. I had this problem with California sales tax which has more than 2000 entries. If this the case, you could try download table for your state from wwww.woosalestax.com. It should fix that problem.

-reply to Parixit
Tax table from their website is one of the solutions I am using right now. If you have too many rows of tax records in your WooCommerce tax table, the tax will not calculate at check out and good luck trying to edit the tax table.  Instead of putting thousands rows of tax record in the table, they have consolidated the table into a lot fewer rows, formatted and ready for import. I don't have any performance issues after using their table on my site. I am just trying to help people that are going through what I went through. Hope this will save their valuable time and frustrations.

Comment: please provide some more description and reliable solution.